# sample rate not working

Tags: android, sensors, sample-rate

I have this line

```
manager.registerListener(sensorListener, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE), logTime);
```

where logTime = 300000000 microseconds = 5 minutes.

I am trying to log every 5 minutes but with this setup it logs every second or so. Do you know what could be wrong or how to solve this?

My manager is a SensorManager.

BR

Comment: ``SensorManager.registerListener`` takes ``rate`` as a hint only. There's no guarantee value you provide is obeyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better setup for your task would be scheduled  alarm waking up your application every 5 minutes.   Then you can register listener and  deregister it ater one sample is received.

Comment: that sounds interesting... but how do I do that?

Comment: You will need broadcast receiver ( read about this in tutorial ) and  scheduled alarm (I would say with wakeup of device - if you like to have proper pressure chart).  You may schedule alarm from your activity, or in case there is  not one,  from another broadcast receiver listening on BOOT_COMPLETE event ( this is safest option, because scheduled alarms do not alsways survive boot )